# Use high resolution (same as desktop) in Linux virtual consoles

Tags: linux, debian, framebuffer, virtual-console

I want to use 1920x1080 in the virtual consoles, with:

- Debian Squeeze;
- proprierary ATI drivers.

Switching back to the open source drivers, it works automatically, but I got no clue with these ones. Someone say I should use `uvesafb` by modifing `initramfs` accordingly. But I didn't find much help around.

Comment: More details on hardware?  Although on my machine with an AMD 785G chipset, it was impossible to get full 1080p on console without using free drivers.  Why do you want to use proprietary drivers?

Comment: ATI Radeon HD 4650. Because running `glxgears`, open source: ~715 FPS; proprietary: ~4490 FPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://blog.samat.org/2010/11/09/High-resolution-text-console-with-uvesafb-and-Debian) post made some light, unfortunately `uvesafb` works only with some modes (according to the [FAQ](http://dev.gentoo.org/~spock/projects/uvesafb/faq.php)) and 1920x1080 isn't in my list. So this doesn't solve my problem, I guess I have to wait the proprietary driver support, if ever will be.

Answer (score 0):

You may try setting kernel's video mode: http://fclose.com/b/2218/

You may first add “vga=ask” parameter to the Linux kernel entry in grub and select one and try what will happen.

Comment: It says: `Legacy 'ask' parameter no longer supported`. Anyway I'm only interested in 1920x1080, and it doesn't appear in the list.